# 'eps' equivalent in Mathematica

Tags: numerics, machine-precision, matlab

In MATLAB, there is a function named `eps`.

> **eps**  Spacing of floating point numbers.
>       D = eps(X), is the positive distance from ABS(X) to the next larger in
>       magnitude floating point number of the same precision as X.
>       X may be either double precision or single precision.
>       For all X, eps(X) is equal to eps(ABS(X)).

Is there an equivalent in *Mathematica*?

**Edit:**

`eps`, with no arguments, is the distance from 1.0 to the next larger double
    precision number, that is `eps` with no arguments returns 2^(-52).

`eps('double')` is the same as `eps`, or `eps(1.0)`.
`eps('single')` is the same as `eps(single(1.0))`, or `single(2^-23)`.

Except for numbers whose absolute value is smaller than REALMIN,
    if 2^E <= ABS(X) < 2^(E+1), then
       eps(X) returns 2^(E-23) if ISA(X,'single')
       eps(X) returns 2^(E-52) if ISA(X,'double')

```
For all X of class double such that ABS(X) <= REALMIN, eps(X)
returns 2^(-1074).   Similarly, for all X of class single such that
ABS(X) <= REALMIN('single'), eps(X) returns 2^(-149).

Replace expressions of the form
   if Y < eps * ABS(X)
with
   if Y < eps(X)

Example return values from calling eps with various inputs are
presented in the table below:

      Expression                   Return Value
     ===========================================
      eps(1/2)                     2^(-53)
      eps(1)                       2^(-52)
      eps(2)                       2^(-51)
      eps(realmax)                 2^971
      eps(0)                       2^(-1074)
      eps(realmin/2)               2^(-1074)
      eps(realmin/16)              2^(-1074)
      eps(Inf)                     NaN
      eps(NaN)                     NaN
     -------------------------------------------
      eps(single(1/2))             2^(-24)
      eps(single(1))               2^(-23)
      eps(single(2))               2^(-22)
      eps(realmax('single'))       2^104
      eps(single(0))               2^(-149)
      eps(realmin('single')/2)    2^(-149)
      eps(realmin('single')/16)   2^(-149)
      eps(single(Inf))             single(NaN)
      eps(single(NaN))             single(NaN)
```

Comment: In my PC, 'MachineEpsilon' return $2.22045 \times 10^{-16}$.

Comment: `Log[2,$MachineEpsilon]==-52`

Comment: `In[425]:= eps[x_Real] := (1 + $MachineEpsilon)*x - x

In[430]:= Log2[Map[eps, {.2, .5, 1., 1.6, 2., 5.5}]]

Out[430]= {-54., -53., -52., -51., -51., -50.}`

Comment: [A closely related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84237). You should be able to take the difference of the original number and the result of `nextafter` to get something equivalent to `eps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a directly equivalent *function* in *Mathematica*.  However, as you comment, [`$MachineEpsilon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineEpsilon.html) (with a `$` character) gives the value of `eps`.

```
$MachineEpsilon
```

> 2.22045*10^-16

If you look at the **Examples > Applications** section of the documentation linked you'll see that `eps(x)` could be defined in Mathematica as:

```
eps[x_:1] := x $MachineEpsilon
```

See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40118/5414) to the somewhat related "Issues with $MachineEpsilon" question.

Answer (score 2):

`Ulp` is a equivalent function in *Mathemtica*,you need `` Needs["ComputerArithmetic`"] `` first

```
Needs["ComputerArithmetic`"]
ComputerArithmetic`Ulp[1]
```

> 1.11022*10^-16

Of course,we can plot it

```
Plot[ComputerArithmetic`Ulp[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to give half epsilon sometimes, but not always.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Could you give a example about what you have encountered?

Comment: Your example above is epsilon over 2.

Comment: E.g. all of these are wrong: ``Table[ComputerArithmetic`Ulp[2^n], {n, 0, 10}]``; but all of these are right: ``Table[ComputerArithmetic`Ulp[1.1*2^n], {n, 0, 10}]``.