# Does Mathematica have an equivalent of C's nextafter?

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

In C (and many other programming languages), there is a function

```
double nextafter(double x, double y)
```

which takes two (IEEE 754) floating-point numbers and returns the next representable floating-point number after `x` in the direction of `y`. What is the *Mathematica* equivalent of this function for `MachinePrecision` numbers?

---

**EDIT:** This issue has been brought up in the comments, but for the benefit of future readers, note that this is a *substantially* more subtle task than simply adding or subtracting `$MachineEpsilon`. The problem is that the distance between one floating-point value and the next changes with magnitude. `$MachineEpsilon`, by definition, is the smallest positive floating-point value such that `1.0 + $MachineEpsilon > 1.0`. The distance between `1.0e-300` and the next number up will be much smaller, while the distance between `1.0e+300` and the next number up will be much greater. In addition, there are issues raised by the transitions between one order of magnitude and the next. Observe that `1.0 + $MachineEpsilon/2 == 1.0`, while `1.0 - $MachineEpsilon/2 < 1.0`.

Comment: `x + Sign[y] $MachineEpsilon` should work, yes?

Comment: @J. M. Not quite. `$MachineEpsilon` is the smallest floating-point number such that `1 + $MachineEpsilon != 1`, but for certain values, the distance to the next representable float is much smaller. For example, consider the distance between `1.0e-300` and the next number up.

Comment: @J. M. If I understand correctly, incrementing/decrementing a float is a rather nontrivial task using only floating-point arithmetic operations. It's much easier with bit-level access to the internal representation of a number, which I can't figure out how to get in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Have a look at `Ulp` et al. in the *Computer Arithmetic* package...

Comment: You're right, for numbers in $(-1, 1)$, adding an appropriate signed machine epsilon would not be applicable. But at least for numbers outside that range, the last one would work.

Comment: @J. M. I still don't believe it would; the gap between `1.0e300` and the next floating-point value is a lot larger than `$MachineEpsilon`. In general, the gaps between consecutive floating-point numbers change with the magnitude of the numbers.

Comment: @ciao `Ulp` is definitely a step in the right direction, but I'm not sure how to use it to implement `nextafter`. In particuar, I'm not sure how to handle the transitions between one exponent value and the next; note that `1.0 + Ulp[1.0] == 1.0` while `1.0 - Ulp[1.0] != 1.0`.

Comment: You can also consider doing something like `{IntegerPart[#1/$MachineEpsilon], #2} & @@ MantissaExponent[x, 2]` to split the floating point number to integer-valued components and working further with those.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you have to program it yourself.  At a boundary `x == 2.^n`, the distance to the next machine real is either `x * $MachineEpsilon` or `x * $MachineEpsilon / 2`.  The documentation for [`MantissaExponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MantissaExponent.html) ambiguously states that the mantissa will be "between $1/b$ and $1$".  It seems be the case that $1/b \le \mathtt{mantissa} < 1$.

```
nextafter[0., y_] := Sign[y] $MinMachineNumber;
nextafter[x_, y_] /; Precision[x] == MachinePrecision := 
  With[{mantexp = MantissaExponent[x, 2]},
   Piecewise[{
      {First[mantexp] + Sign[y] $MachineEpsilon/4., 
       Sign[x] Sign[y] < 0 && First[mantexp] == 1./2.}},
     First[mantexp] + Sign[y] $MachineEpsilon/2.] * 2.^Last[mantexp]
   ];
```

A couple of tests:

```
Block[{x = 128. - 128*$MachineEpsilon/2},
 Print @ RealDigits[{nextafter[x, -1], x, nextafter[x, 1]}, 2];
 Differences[{nextafter[x, -1], x, nextafter[x, 1]}]
 ]
(*
{{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 7},
 {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 7},
 {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 8}}
{1.42109*10^-14, 1.42109*10^-14}
*)

Block[{x = 128.},
 Print @ RealDigits[{nextafter[x, -1], x, nextafter[x, 1]}, 2];
 Differences[{nextafter[x, -1], x, nextafter[x, 1]}]
 ]
(*
{{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 7},
 {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 8},
 {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 8}}
{1.42109*10^-14, 2.84217*10^-14}
*)
```

---

To deal with subnormal numbers, one has to use `Compile`, ASAIK.

```
nextafter = With[{min = $MinMachineNumber},
 Compile[{x, y},
  Block[{e, laste},
    If[x == 0,
       Sign[y] min/2.^52,
    If[x < 1,
       e = 2.^(Ceiling @ Log2 @ Abs[x] + 52);
       laste = e*2^-52,
       laste = e = 2.^Ceiling[Log2 @ Abs[x] - 52]];
    While[x + Sign[y] e != x,
          laste = e; e = e/2.];
    x + Sign[y] laste]],
  RuntimeOptions -> {"CompareWithTolerance" -> False}]]
```

You'll get an error on `$MaxMachineNumber` depending on the direction.  I hope I haven't tripped over any other boundary traps.

Comment: Have you considered IEEE denormal numbers?

Comment: @kirma Nope.  They're hard to get with *M* functions, but I believe they're possible in `Compile`.  They tend to get converted to arb. prec. numbers, if you operate with them.  Do you think the OP wants that?  I'm not familiar with the C `nextafter`.

Comment: I'm just doubtful of these nasty corner cases. I'm not really aware what typical usage scenarios of `nextafter` are - I want to stick to integer C programming. :)

Comment: @kirma, sometimes floating point arithmetic is fun; most of the time, it's a PITA to worry about. ;)

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, one can exploit the behavior of `Interval[]` when applied to a machine-precision number to obtain the previous and next representable machine-precision numbers (thanks to Szabolcs for the fix):

```
SetAttributes[nextafter, Listable];
nextafter[x_?MachineNumberQ, s_?NumericQ] /; s != 0 :=
         First[Interval[x]][[ -Sign[s - x] ]]
```

To obtain a result equivalent to Michael's two test cases:

```
With[{x = 128. - 128*$MachineEpsilon/2},
     {RealDigits[{nextafter[x, 127], x, nextafter[x, 129]}, 2], 
      Differences[{nextafter[x, 127], x, nextafter[x, 129]}]}]
```

and

```
With[{x = 128.},
     {RealDigits[{nextafter[x, 127], x, nextafter[x, 129]}, 2], 
      Differences[{nextafter[x, 127], x, nextafter[x, 129]}]}]
```

Additionally:

```
nextafter[0., {-1, 1}] === {-1, 1} $MinMachineNumber
   True
```

A caveat of this function is its inability to deal with subnormals.

Comment: Looks good but to do precisely what `nextafter` does, it should be `Sign[s-x]`.  I realized this by playing a bit with C's `nextafter`.  Michael's also uses `s`, and not `s-x` as a relative direction, so this function is equivalent to his.  It's maybe interesting to note that this doesn't deal with subnormal numbers either (but C's `nextafter` does)

Comment: I don't know much about denormal numbers.  It appears that Mathematica generally switches to arbitrary precision at the point when it would get into the denormal range.  `Precision@Last@First@Interval[0.] === MachinePrecision` but `Precision[0.5 * Last@First@Interval[0.]] === 15.9546`.  However, if I return a denormal number from C, it can do calculations with it while keeping it as `MachinePrecision`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a C compiler you could use C's `nextafter` directly.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
ClearAll[nextafter]
"
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion() {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {}

DLLEXPORT int nextafterM(
        WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res
) {
    double x = MArgument_getReal(Args[0]);
    double y = MArgument_getReal(Args[1]);

    double result = nextafter(x, y);

    MArgument_setReal(Res, result);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
";
CreateLibrary[%, "nextafter", "CompileOptions" -> "-Wall"]
nextafter = LibraryFunctionLoad[%, "nextafterM", {Real, Real}, Real]
```

Which gives:

```
x = 1.*^-300;
RealDigits[#, 2] & /@ {nextafter[x, -1.], x, nextafter[x, 1.]}
(* {{{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, -996},
    {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, -996}
    {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, -996}}} *)

x = 1.*^300;
RealDigits[#, 2] & /@ {nextafter[x, 0.], x, nextafter[x, 2 x]}
(* {{{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 997},
    {{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 997}
    {{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 997}}} *)
```

Comment: To compile with Visual Studio `<mathl.h>` is needed..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the most straightforward way goes through `RealDigits`:

```
nextAfter[x_Real] := 
 FromDigits[MapAt[1 + # &, MapAt[0*# &, RealDigits[x, 2], 1], {1, -1}], 2] + x
```