# How does Internal`CompareNumeric work?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, undocumented

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118808/1871), 
[Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) mentioned an undocumented function `` Internal`CompareNumeric `` and briefly explained its usage as follows:

> `` Internal`CompareNumeric[prec, a, b] `` returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`
>   according to whether `a` is less, equal, or greater than `b` when
>   compared at the precision of `a` or `b` (whichever is less) minus
>   `prec` decimal digits of "tolerance". It is the fundamental operation
>   underlying `Less`, `Equal`, `Greater`, `LessEqual` etc. for
>   finite-precision numeric types.

…To be honest, I failed to understand this description. In my eyes, it seems to suggest that, `` Internal`CompareNumeric `` will compare

```
With[{minPre = Precision /@ {a, b} // Min}, N[{a, b}, minPre - prec]]
```

but it's not true, because

```
Internal`CompareNumeric[1, 1.1`2, 1.2`2]
(* -1 *)
```

while the output should be `0` in my understanding.

Can someone explain the usage of `` Internal`CompareNumeric `` in a more detailed way?

Comment: my guess the comparison is actually made directly on the binary representation and the "decimal digits" count only approximately translates to a specific number of base 2 digits.

Comment: @george2079 Hmm… but ``Internal`CompareNumeric[1, 11`2, 12`2]`` still gives `-1`.

Comment: FYI, the split point of `-1` and `0` is around`7.3456427360042`

Comment: I was discussing this with yode the other day. ``Internal`CompareNumeric[n,a,b]`` basically answers the question, "how do `a` and `b` related ignoring `n` points of precision". So if you have two numbers and drop `$MachinePrecision` points of precision it's basically comparing them at the integer level. e.g. ``Internal`CompareNumeric[IntegerPart@$MachinePrecision, 2.1, 2] `` (because my `$MachinePrecision` isn't an int) gives 0, but ``Internal`CompareNumeric[IntegerPart@$MachinePrecision - 1, 2.1, 2]`` gives 1.

Comment: @MB1965 Well, but how to explain the behavior of the last code piece in my question?

Comment: I just figured it assumes all numbers have `$MachinePrecision` points of precision. Because internally they do. That precision specification is just some top-level thing. It's an internal function after all. So it only uses the `1.1` from ``1.1`2``.  I'm betting when you have something like ``1.0001`2. == 1.0`` it's really ``Internal`CompareNumeric[$MachinePrecision-2, 1.0001, 1.0]``.

Comment: Although as @happyfish notes that's not actually right because that would give equal in that case.

Comment: @MB1965 Sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. What's "not actually right"? And I'm afraid you've lost the bet because, for example, ``Internal`CompareNumeric[9, 1.0001`2, 1.0]`` gives `0`, while ``Internal`CompareNumeric[9, 1.0001, 1.0]`` gives `1`.

Comment: That's what I meant. That formula isn't right, because there's that odd switch point that @happyfish found.

Comment: @MB1965 Yeah. I tried to make formulas according to the docs with attempts on binary and logarithm, but yet not able to get that number

Comment: @happyfish any idea given that that the `$MachinePrecision` docs suggest it'll be `53 Log10[2.]`? (which I realize now is just `Log10[2^53]`...)

Comment: @MB1965 Yes, the split point for all machine precision integers has that split point

Comment: @happyfish if you plot the number of points you have to remove past the ~15 done in the answer given it's clearly linear starting at `$MachinePrecision`. Before that it has a weird log shape. I'll post a supplementary answer to that maybe will give you ideas. No log function I've tried fits it though.

Comment: @MB1965 thank you very much

Comment: Additional question: Why does ``Internal`CompareNumeric`` give an error message when `prec` is set smaller than `$MinPrecision`?

Comment: Your *500* rep is so hot,which is out of my expectation.But it looks like it's going to be expired soon? :)

Comment: @yode Out of my expection, too :D . To be honest I'm now having a hard time judging the answers I recieved 囧. Anyway I'll award it in time, just as I always did :) .

Answer (score 7):

This is just to highlight another aspect of the other answer given. I would have expected a linear progression from the definition. I.e., if `Precision[n]=p` then we'd expect the switch point for `CompareNumeric[x, n, n+epsilon]` to be `p`. And this holds once you get past `$MachinePrecision`. Probably happens when Mathematica has to go from 64 bit numbers to whatever its internal infinite-precision numeric is. We can see this here:

```
pr[x_] :=
  SelectFirst[
   Range[1, 100, .1],
   Internal`CompareNumeric[#, SetPrecision[1.1`, x], 1.2`100] == 0 &
   ];

Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> Gray],
 {#, pr@#} & /@ Range[1, 25, .01] // ListPlot
 ]
```

[image: blah]

I looked at the part for `n < $MachinePrecision` and thought: "oh, a log-type function (probably log2)". But no simple scaling on `Log2` worked for me.

```
Show[ListLinePlot@Table[Table[x*N@Log2[n], {n, 15}], {x, 5}], 
 ListPlot[{#, pr@#} & /@ Range[1, 15, .01]]]
```

[image: log2]

So maybe someone else can tackle what sort of pre-form that is. Once we have that we can probably piece back how Mathematica is interpreting things for its sub-machine precision numbers.

#### Update

As found by happy fish, `$MachinePrecision - $MachinePrecision/x` fits this really well:

```
Plot[{
  pr[x],
  $MachinePrecision - $MachinePrecision/x
  },
 {x, 1, $MachinePrecision}
 ]
```

[image: fitted]

Noting that `$MachinePrecision` is `53Log10[2]` by simple log rearrangements we have `Log10[2^(53*(1 - 1/x))]`. Since `$MachinePrecision` comes from how a 64 bit number is stored (there are 53 bits of precision), this could be saying it's using `53*(1 - 1/x)` bits of precision for these numbers with `Precision` specified below `$MachinePrecision`. Why that would be, I have no idea. But it's a possibility.

#### Update 2

Shadowray points out this is even odder when you have fewer points of precision available before they would be equivalent

For example, make `pr` multivariate:

```
pr[x_, y_: 1] :=
  SelectFirst[
   Range[1, 100, .1],
   With[{
     a = SetPrecision[1. + (10^(-y)), x],
     b = SetPrecision[1. + (2*10^(-y)), 100]
     },
    Internal`CompareNumeric[#, a, b] == 0 &
    ]
   ];
```

Now plotting this for different amounts of reduction:

```
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> Gray],
 Table[
   {#, pr[#, n]} & /@ Range[1, 25, .05],
   {n, 17}
   ] // ListPlot
 ]
```

[image: changingprec]

Note that the first 6 curves actually continue. They just jump up to `y=x` after `$MachinePrecision` (as I would naively have predicted).

If we use a near-continuous change:

```
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> Gray],
 Table[
   {#, pr[#, n]} & /@ Range[1, 25, .05],
   {n, Range[1, 17, .1]}
   ] // ListPlot
 ]
```

[image: continuous]

The pre-discontinuity part can still be easily formulated:

```
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> Gray],
 Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[$MachinePrecision (1 - n/x),
    {n, 16}],
  {x, 1, $MachinePrecision}],
 Table[
   {#, pr[#, n]} & /@ Range[1, 25, .1],
   {n, 17}
   ] // ListPlot
 ]
```

[image: shifting]

What's happening at the discontinuities is somewhat less clear. Note that the oddity at 17 is from the fact that `10^-17` is smaller than `10^-$MachinePrecision` and so the system just treats the addition as doing nothing. The jumps need more explanation though.

In any case, if we return to the storage argument, now we have `53 n/x` bits being dropped, assuming the interpreting the pre-jump part of the curves as showing `Log10[2^(53 (1 - n/x))]` is valid.

Comment: @xzczd made the `pr` much more sensitive. Shows the real discontinuity at `$MachinePrecision` now.

Comment: I got similar plots. Although I used `FindFormula` to get very close fits, but those forms and coefficients do not make sense...

Comment: @happyfish It honestly looks like a -1/r  thing (but shifted vertically). Simple (16+-1/r) is way too steep though.

Comment: `$MachinePrecision -17.217894/x` no idea

Comment: @happyfish Wow. That fits perfectly. Who knows if it's right. Maybe someone brighter than myself will see that and be able to explain why it works. Maybe it's supposed to be `$MachinePrecision - $MachinePrecision / x`? That's just as good a fit, I think.

Comment: I think I have found the exact formula, proceeding to the final step...

Comment: What if one uses ``Internal`CompareNumeric[#, 
 SetPrecision[1.0000000001`, x], 1.0000000002`100]`` in `pr` function?

Comment: @Shadowray fun point. I think it'll be possible to explain that.

Answer (score 5):

After some experiments I found some of the "rules" with which `` Internal`CompareNumeric[c, a, b] `` operates. If you find any exceptions please notify me. Lets denote `minpr = Min[Precision[a],Precision[b]]`. If `c` is greater than `pr[minpr]` then `` Internal`CompareNumeric[c, a, b] `` kind of throw away anything after the point. The function `pr` depends on `a` and `b`, the only symmetry I was able to detect is that if `minpr>15`, `pr[minpr]=minpr` (maybe connected to `MachinePrecision`?). The following figure is a possible `pr[]`.

[image]

Comment: What is `pr[]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 An assumed function relationship between `minpr` and the threshold?

Comment: @xzczd There's no definition of `pr[]` in your OP, nor code for it. I notice MB1965 has a code for it (but no definition other than the code). Is it the same as used here? Since the ordering of answers changes over time (this was the top answer when I read it), it would be helpful to point to the definition of `pr[]` or give the code, if it's different. In the answer, "The following figure is a possible `pr[]`" suggests to me that there might be various ways to define `pr[]` and the plot is a possible one.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In my understanding, `pr[]` is more of a guess in this answer,. (BTW this is indeed the earlest answer. ) Anyway let's wait for Most Perfect Username's clarification :)

Comment: @xzczd A guess at what? There's no def. But yes, I think the OP can easily clarify.

Comment: @MichaelE2 and @xzczd, `pr[]` is just a function with which help ``Internal`CompareNumeric`` works (imho), as I mentioned I don't know it's full form (@MB1965 answer is more complete at this regards), but nevertheless  it's easy to get  `pr[]` empiric, for concrete `a`, `b`, `c` (I think the method is obvious, but if you want I can write examples). The connection between ``Internal`CompareNumeric`` and `pr[]` is in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm afraid I'm still clueless and starting to feel stupid. You, MB1965, and @xzczd seem to know what `pr[]` represents and how to compute it. It does not show up in ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@Internal`CompareNumeric`` (nothing does). Let me ask another way: What is the code for your plot of `pr[]`? How were the coordinates of the points computed?

Comment: @MichaelE2 , lets look at an example, ``Internal`CompareNumeric[c, 2`2, 2.1`40]`` depending on c it gives `0` or `-1` , [plot](http://imgur.com/tgfIch7). 
In this case ``pr[Min[Precision[2`2],Precision[2`40]]]=5``,
If you get all results for ``Internal`CompareNumeric[c, a`pra, b`prb]`` for any `pra`, `prb` you get `pr[]`.(I have difficulties in adding the plot...)

Comment: Thanks, again.  So is this a definition of `pr[]`?: "`pr[a, b]` returns the least `prec` for which ``Internal`CompareNumeric[prec, a, b]`` returns `0`." (That's the sort of thing I was looking for.)  So it might be computed with ``FindRoot[Abs@Internal`CompareNumeric[c, 2`2, 2.1`40] == 1/2, {c, 0, 1000}]`` (ignoring the unimportant error messages)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, but I think you mean "returns not `0`"? For the second question` also yes (from first glance, if I have time I will think more about it).

Answer (score 5):

In this answer I will present an overall simulation of `` Internal`CompareNumeric ``'s behavior. Throughout this answer, there are four variables: `` Internal`CompareNumeric[tol, a, b] ``, `first=Min[Abs[a],Abs[b]]` `diff=Abs[a-b]` and `prec` is the **minimum** precision of the two specified. Here's my findings so far

- For exact arithmetic, `` Internal`CompareNumeric `` gives correct answer regardless of `tol`.
- For machine precision integers (`1.`, `2.`), the split point is always `$MachinePrecision`.
- The order and sign of `a`, `b` does not matter, the minimum precision is used for calculation(this can be implied from my definition above).
- The smallest `prec` that makes the two numbers comparable is $-\log_{10}(\frac{diff}{first+diff})$ (this number comes from the definition of [Precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html)), i.e. when $prec>-\log_{10}(\frac{diff}{first+diff})$, there exist a `tol`, such that the function returns `-1` or `1`; when `prec` is less than this number, the function returns `0` for all `tol` settings.
- When $prec\in [-\log_{10}(\frac{diff}{first+diff}),\$MachinePrecision]$, there exist a split point $y$, such that when $tol<y$, the function returns `-1` or `1`, when $tol>y$, the function returns `0`. The analytical formula with `first`, `diff`, `prec` as parameters is $$y(first,diff,prec)=\$MachinePrecision (1+\frac{1}{prec}\log_{10}(\frac{diff}{first+diff}))$$
- <del>For `prec>$MachinePrecision`, the split point of `tol` is exactly the same as `prec`</del>.
- For `prec>$MachinePrecision`, the formula above is incorrect. Some experiments show that when the ratio of `first` and `diff` is big enough, the comparison is converted to exact arithmetic(independent of `tol`). There should be two such points when `diff/first` is small and big,  I haven't worked on it yet. <del>A quick fixed of the formula is `y[prec,first,diff]=prec-If[#>8,#,0]&[-Log10[diff/(first+diff)]]`</del>, I will make careful research later when I have time.

The following is the code version of the findings above:

```
fishCompareNumeric[tol_, a_, b_] := 
 With[{first = Min[Abs@a, Abs@b], diff = Abs[a - b], prec = Precision@{a, b}},
  Module[{split},
   Catch[
    split = Piecewise[{
       {Throw@Sign[a - b], prec === Infinity},
       {$MachinePrecision, prec === MachinePrecision},
       {Throw@0, prec < -Quiet@Log10[diff/(first + diff)]},
       {$MachinePrecision (1 + Log10[diff/(first + diff)]/prec), -Log10[diff/(
           first + diff)] <= prec <= $MachinePrecision},
       {prec, prec > $MachinePrecision}
       }];
    Piecewise[{
      {Sign[a - b], tol < split}
      }]]]]
```

Here is a plot of my binary search for approximate values, with parameters(OP's example) `first=1.1`, `diff=0.1`, horizontal axis being `prec` and vertical axis being split point (of `tol`).

[image]

You may notice the two vertical lines at around `1.07` and `16`, they are introduced by the sudden value changes, at the two points in my formula.

Here is a plot of my exact formula with same parameters
[image]

Code for binary search approximation:

```
splitPointBinary[{{val1_, val2_}, {low_, up_}}] := 
 With[{mid = Internal`CompareNumeric[(low + up)/2, val1, val2]}, 
  If[Internal`CompareNumeric[low, val1, val2] == 
    mid, {{val1, val2}, {(low + up)/2, up}}, {{val1, 
     val2}, {low, (low + up)/2}}]]
splitPointApprox[first_, diff_, prec_] := 
 FixedPoint[
   splitPointBinary, {{SetPrecision[first, prec], 
     SetPrecision[first + diff, prec]}, {0.1, 1000}}][[2, 1]]
```

Code for my formula:

```
splitPoint[first_, diff_, prec_] := 
 Piecewise[{{$MachinePrecision (1 + Log10[diff/(first + diff)]/prec), 
    -Log10[diff/(first + diff)] < prec < $MachinePrecision}, {prec, 
    prec > $MachinePrecision}}]
```

For OP's example,

```
splitPointApprox[1.1, 0.1, 2]
(*7.34564*)
splitPoint[1.1, 0.1, 2]
(*7.34564*)
```

Another one,

```
splitPointApprox[2.2, 0.5, 6]
(*14.0071*)
splitPoint[2.2, 0.5, 6]
(*14.0071*)
```

Comment: This looks strange for `splitPointApprox[1.1, 0.0000000000001, 2]`

Comment: @xzczd answer updated.

Comment: I took the liberty to add a function interpreted from your findings to your answer, feel free to edit or roll back if you don't like it :) .

Comment: @xzczd I like it :)

Comment: Since I haven't think out a systematic enough way to judge the answer, I'll leave it unaccepted for a while, but this is undoubtfully the most plausible answer I received so far, +51 :) .

Comment: @xzczd thanks for you generous award! I hope these can be researched more deeply and proved more rigorously in the future:)

Comment: Try ``fishCompareNumeric[40, 1.`40 10^10, 1.`40 10^10 + 10^1000]``

Comment: Actually, that is not. The same happens at the a lot less extreme ``fishCompareNumeric[40, 1.`40 10^10, 1.`40 10^10 + 10^3]``, where `num = Log10[10^3/(1.`40 10^10+10^3)]` is not small at all. Moreover, there is an issue at ``fishCompareNumeric[35, 1.`40 10^10, 1.`40 10^10 + 10^2]``. In general, your formula does not seem to reproduce the correct switch over point in `diff` for `prec > $MachinePrecision`.

Comment: @mmeent Thanks for pointing that out. It does appear the offset of the split point formula is incorrect in some cases after machine precision (but the slope is still one). I admit I did not think much on the formula for this part. Since I do not have much spare time on weekdays, so I will update my answer by this Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a slightly different approach than above. For `` Internal`CompareNumeric[prec, a, a+ε] ``, lets fix `prec` and `a` and find the threshold value for `ε` for which this switches from `0` to `-1`. For this purpose I define the following function

```
tf[p_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=
   Internal`CompareNumeric[
     p,
     SetPrecision[1, y],
     SetPrecision[1, y] + 10^-SetPrecision[z, 100]
]
```

That is we take `a = SetPrecision[1, y]` and `ε = 10^-SetPrecision[p, 100]`. (The `SetPrecision` in the definition of `ε` is there to avoid that the precision of z in the input can affect the outcome in anyway.)

We can then find the threshold value using simple bisection. For example abusing FindRoot:

```
tf2[p_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (z /. 
  FindRoot[tf[p, y, z] == -1/2, {z, -10, p + y + 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100, MaxIterations -> 20])
```

Plotting the threshold value as a function of `y` for values of `p` we get
[image]

The top curve (`p=0`) is simply given by `z = y`. More generally the behavior of `tf2` is modelled precisely by

```
Max[
 Piecewise[
  {
   {y - p, y > MP},
   {((MP - p)/MP) y, y < MP}
  }
 ],
 MP/2 UnitStep[y - Max[MP, p]]
]
```

where

```
MP=$MachinePrecision
```

What does this tell us about the behavior of `` Internal`CompareNumeric[prec,a,b] ``? Well, if the precision of `a` and `b` is set higher than machine precision and `prec` is not too large, the behavior is exactly as described by Oleksandr R.

It becomes a bit weirder when `prec` is large (compared to the precision of `a` and `b`), in which case there is an apparent upperbound of on the threshold difference of `ε = 10^(-MP/2)`.

I don't quite understand the behavior of the threshold when the precision of `a` and `b` is smaller than machine precision. Maybe somebody else can shed some light.

**Update:**

Based on the above we can venture to propose a mock version of `` Internal`CompareNumeric[prec, a, b] ``:

```
MockCompareNumeric[p_,a_,b_]:=With[
 {ip = Min[Precision[a], Precision[b]]},
  With[
   {ep = Which[
    ip === MachinePrecision, MP-p
    ip >= Max[MP, p], Max[ip - p, MP/2],
    True, Max[(1 - p/MP) ip, 0]
    ]
   },
   If[N[ Abs[a - b]/Max[Abs[a], Abs[b]]] < N[10^-ep], 0, Sign[a-b]] 
 ]
];
```

I have tested the behavior of this mock function with the actual `` Internal`CompareNumeric `` over a large range of `prec`, `a` `b`, and they match. (**edit 3.4.2017**: adjusted the mock function to get the correct behavior for MachinePrecision input.)

**Addendum**

Ofcourse, the actual `` Internal`CompareNumeric `` would not work like this. Instead it probably uses some low level functions working directly on the internal representation of the arbitrary precision numbers. (It certainly is a lot faster) However, the mock function gives us a fairly good idea of the behavior of `` Internal`CompareNumeric[prec,a,b] ``.

In short it determines some effective precision (`ep` in the mock function) from `prec` and the minimal precision of the inputs `a` and `b` and then determines whether `a > b` within a precision tolerance set by `ep`.

The difference between the behavior of `ep` dependent on whether the input precision is larger or smaller than machine precision probably arises due to differences in implementation leveraging the fact that for precision smaller than machine precision, Mathematica represents its arbitrary precision numbers simply as a pair of machine numbers representing the value and the precision of the number, in which case it can leverage various machine operations to do the comparison. I suspect that similarly the lower bounds on `ep` arise some checks that can be down efficiently using low level functions. The scaling of `ep` when `ip < MP` presumably is some design choice relating to the desired functionality, possibly related with wanting the effective precision to be larger than zero for reasonable values of `prec`.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84237), by any chance?

Comment: @ J.M. No I hadn't. I am also not sure why you are pointing to it. Could you explain?

Comment: You mentioned wanting to find the threshold value where two numbers are no longer the same, so I think a function that would give the "next" floating point number might suit your needs.

Comment: @ J.M. Ah, I see. Well, in this case we are not interested in finding the threshold where the two numbers are no longer considered the "same"  by ``Internal`CompareNumeric`` which is a slightly different question, than find the threshold where the internal representation becomes the same. (Arbitrary precision numbers in Mathematica can have many more digits in their internal representation than their actual precision value.)

Comment: What if one evaluates ``MockCompareNumeric[5, -0.9252872333493522561`2., 0.9289648686205458361`3.]`` ?

Comment: @Shadowray: I guess the denominator may need to be Abs[a]+Abs[b] rather than Abs[a+b]

Comment: Note that the mock function easily reproduces the odd behavior observed in the other answers.

Comment: I'm afraid the guess `ε = 10^(-$MachinePrecision/2)` is incorrect, if you modify `tf` to ``tf[tol_?NumericQ, prec_?NumericQ, digit_?NumericQ] := 
 Internal`CompareNumeric[tol, SetPrecision[100, prec], 
  SetPrecision[100, prec] + 10^-SetPrecision[digit, 100]]``, you will find the split digit seems to become `$MachinePrecision/2 - 2`

Comment: @xzczd It is indeed the case that the absolute tolerance `ε` is no longer `10^(-$MachinePrecision/2)` in that case. But the "effective precision" `ep` as it appears in the mock function is still `$MachinePrecision/2`. That is where the division by Abs[a]+Abs[b] comes in. (Actually I've found that it is not quite  `$MachinePrecision/2`, but somewhere close to that, i.e. within 1%.