# What do the Internal`Compare* functions do?

Tags: sorting, undocumented

As part of looking at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31261/38205) I dug into `` Names["Internal`*Compare*"] `` and ended up with:

`` {Internal`CompareToPAT, Internal`CompareNumeric, Internal`ComparePatterns} ``

I was guessing they served as the backbone of whatever the canonical ordering is, but on further exploration they're related, but perhaps entirely disjoint from it. Well, `CompareNumeric` does tell us about ordering. But the other two seem to tell us about difference, but not ordering.

`CompareNumeric` has been explored [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140528/how-does-internalcomparenumeric-work) but the others haven't been treated on the site, it seems.

Here's my brief understanding that hopefully others will be able to expand:

#### `` Internal`ComparePatterns ``

As jkuczm points out, this actually has a good discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7904/38205).

This seems to be part of the pattern matcher (or something). Consider these cases:

```
Internal`ComparePatterns @@@ {
  {_, _},
  {_, __},
  {_, ___},
  {_, _String},
  {_, 1 ...},
  {2 ..., 1 ...},
  {Optional[_, 1], _},
  {Optional[_, 1], Optional[_, 2]},
  {a_, _}
  }

{"Identical", "Specific", "Specific", "Incomparable", "Incomparable", \
"Disjoint", "Incomparable", "Equivalent", "Equivalent"}
```

I think I've covered the core pattern classes, but what do they mean? What is `"Specific"`? Why are `_` and `_String` incomparable?

#### `` Internal`CompareToPAT ``

This seems to specify the position of first structural difference? Consider:

```
Internal`CompareToPAT @@@ {
  {a, a},
  {1, 2},
  {"1", 2},
  {"A", "a"},
  {g[1], g[2]},
  {g[1, 1], g[1, 2]},
  {\[Pi], N@\[Pi]},
  {g["c", "b"], g["c", "d"]}
  }

{True, {{"Structural difference", 
   None, {}}}, {{"Structural difference", 
   None, {}}}, {{"Structural difference", 
   None, {}}}, {{"Structural difference", 
   None, {1}}}, {{"Structural difference", 
   None, {2}}}, True, {{"Structural difference", None, {2}}}}
```

But is everything a `"StructuralDifference"`? Why do they come as a list-in-a-list? It doesn't let me pass more than 2 arguments to it. And what is that `None`?

I know this is open-ended, but I think understanding it would be useful at the very least for understanding internal implementation details, even if it won't help elucidate how `Sort` does its thing.

Can anyone provide more info?

Comment: As to ``Internal`ComparePatterns`` there's [How to generally match, unify and merge patterns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2918/14303).

Comment: You can play with ``Internal`CompareToPAT`` options to see different results than `{"Structural difference", None, ...}`

Comment: @jkuczm do you have a suggestion of what sort of manipulations to start with? In particular I don't quite understand how a `Tolerance`, `AccuracyGoal`, or `PerformanceGoal` really makes sense here.

Comment: Since it's undocumented I also don't know details, but it seems ``Internal`CompareToPAT`` is testing some form of equality of expressions with details controlled by those options. Check for example: ``Internal`CompareToPAT[{1., 1.}, {2., 3.}, Tolerance -> #] & /@ {None, 
  10, 100}``, or ``Internal`CompareToPAT[{1., 1.}, {2., 3.}, PrecisionGoal -> #] & /@ {0,
   None, 1}``

Comment: @jkuczm good example there. I've been working in a sort-of similar way and still am very confused.